# Disjunction elimination rule in Coq?

Tags: coq

I was surprised to not find a built-in proposition for disjunction elimination in Coq:

```
P \/ ~ P -> (P -> C) -> (~ P -> C) -> C
```

How can I prove it without tactics? Only using Curry/Howard isomorphism.

Comment: Please use code formatting (four-space-indented blocks/backtick-enclosed inline text) when necessary. This question does not render properly without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does exist. It's called `or_ind`.

```
Check or_ind.
(*   : forall A B P : Prop,
       (A -> P) -> (B -> P) -> A \/ B -> P *)
(* shuffling arguments to get your signature *)
Check (fun (P C : Prop) (p : P \/ ~P) (l : P -> C) (r : ~P -> C) => or_ind l r p).
```

Deeper than that, this functionality is really part of the definition of `or` itself. `or` is an inductive type, and every inductive type comes with rules for using it in the primitive `match` construct. `or_ind` is just a wrapper to let you use that `match` in function form. Your function/theorem would be implemented, in terms of `match`, as

```
fun (P C : Prop) (p : P \/ ~P) (l : P -> C) (r : ~P -> C) =>
  match p with
  | or_introl p => l p
  | or_intror p => r p
  end
```

Comment: is there something like find_theorems command in Isabelle to find such theorems?

Comment: @Javier  If you generalize your lemma you should  be able to find it using `Search (?P \/ ?Q -> (?P -> ?C) -> (?Q -> ?C) -> ?C).` (I haven’t actually tried the command, hope it works)